# removing specific lines in text with respect to floating point number

Tags: text-processing

I have a data file consists of strings and digit numbers with four columns as follows;

```
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.705667828 4212835.982693942 -2545104.648264054
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.702108623 4212836.006039822 -2545104.654250688
ALIC00AUS_R_20183350000.gz -4052052.694316 4212835.990059 -2545104.643113
```

I need to remove all lines includes 6 floating point numbers. The original size of the data file consists of several thousands of lines. The minimum floating point number is always 6 among the all numbers.

Comment: Do you want to remove only 6 floating point numbers, or also 5,4, ... floating point?

Comment: Could you please [edit] and add an example output?

Comment: The only interpretation of your question that makes sense to me is that you want to delete lines where the floating point numbers have 6 digits *after the decimal point*. Is that correct? if so, should the condition be applied to any number or every number in the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -v -E "\.[0-9]{6}\b" input.txt >output.txt
```

Here a visual explanation of the command: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-v+-E+%22%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B6%7D%5Cb%22+input.txt+%3Eoutput.txt

And here the regex `\.[0-9]{6}\b` (https://regex101.com/r/bz5Dzr/1):

- `\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]{6}

  - {6} Quantifier — Matches exactly 6 times
  - 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
- `\b` assert position at a word boundary